# a robust way to toggle item display in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle whether to display an item I should do the following:

```
$(item).css("display", "none")
$(item).css("display", "block")
```

But this method is not robust enough, given that the item might be "display: flex" or "display: table".

I think in `react`, I can just delete that element and re-render it when I need to, but is there any simple way to do that using `jQuery` besides directly modify the html to delete that element?

Thanks.

Comment: `$(item).toggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `toggleClass()` in case you are working with flex then it would be a better approach to keep the flex properties in a separate class and add/remove or in easy words `toggle` the flex class if you want to hide or show that container with defaults set to `display:none` in a separate class, in this way either the container is `flex` or `table` it works either ways see the example below

```js
$(".show").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).siblings('.my-item').css('display') == 'flex') {
    $(this).siblings('.my-item').toggleClass('myflex');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('.my-item').toggleClass('myTable');
  }


})
```

```css
.my-item {
  display: none;
}

.myflex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.myTable {
  display: block;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 5px dashed #c8c8c8;
}

.show {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a class="show">TOGLLE THIS ITEM</a>
  <div class="my-item myflex">1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="show">TOGLLE THIS ITEM</a>
  <div class="my-item myflex">2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="show">TOGLLE THIS ITEM</a>
  <div class="my-item myTable">TABLE DISPLAY
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="show">TOGLLE THIS ITEM</a>
  <div class="my-item myflex">3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="show">TOGLLE THIS ITEM</a>
  <div class="my-item myflex">4
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <a class="show">TOGLLE THIS ITEM</a>
  <div class="my-item myflex">5
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a custom css class and switch them using below. This would also give a bit more control over styling.

```
$(item).addClass('display-none');
$(item).removeClass('display-none');
$(item).removeClass('display-none display-flex'); // For removing multiple classes
```

and for example the css properties would be like

```
.display-none{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
$(item).css("display", "none")
```

and assign the `flex` or `table` value of the `display` property to any custom attribute, e.g. `$(item).attr("disp_prop","flex")` and on returning back to display you can do a simple.

```
$(item).css("display", $(item).attr("disp_prop"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use jQuery's show/hide functions?

```
$(item).hide();
$(item).show();
```

hide function is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ), except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value. ([from jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/))

```js
$('#btnToggle').click(function(){
  if($('#item').is(':visible')) 
  {
    $('#item').hide();
  }
  else 
  {
    $('#item').show();
  }
  
  $('#log').html("Current display state: " + $('#item').css('display'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnToggle">toggle</button>

<div id="item" style="display: flex;">
  flex div
</div>

<div id="log">
</div>
```

Comment: `.hide()` wont effect on the `display:flex;` it sets he `display:block;` or `none` you should read the OP requirements carefully

Comment: How .hide() does not affect display:flex ? I just added code snippet special for you. Please check that!

Comment: yes you are right in this sense but what i was talking about was specifially with bootstrap is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/ht94wbtr/8/), try to hide the disabled `li`s under heading **with d-flex class (used for badge)** using `.hide()`

Comment: Ok I understand, in the link you mentioned d-flex has display: flex!important; and important is reason hide will not work. But in original question there is not mentioned important, so I think my answer is not wrong. Thanks

Comment: yes but bootstrap is the commonly used and every now and then we have it included and when utilizing the bootstrap classes you will eventually have to revert it to `toggleClass` which  works in both cases wither your or the one I am talking about